# Angular budgets: define one budget for any lazy loaded module

Tags: angular

I do not find an answer to my question.

in `angular.json` you can set budgets like

```
"budgets": [
 {
   "type": "bundle",
   "name": "foo-module",
   "maximumError": "1mb"
 },
{
   "type": "bundle",
   "name": "bar-module",
   "maximumError": "1mb"
 }

]
```

So i need to set a rule per lazy loaded module. However is there a possiblity to set a general rule so that any bundle should not exceed certain limits?